# Custom Post Type archive page not being used in Timber/Twig WordPress setup

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, custom-post-type, timber

The problem: our WordPress installation is using archive.php for an archive page instead of the desired archive-article.php.

Here is our configuration:

functions.php

```
register_post_type(
            'article',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __('Articles'),
                    'singular_name' => __('Article'),
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-media-default',
                'menu_position' => 4,
                'taxonomies' => array('article_type'),
                'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail')
            )
        );
```

archive-article.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * Methods for TimberHelper can be found in the /lib sub-directory
 *
 * @package  WordPress
 * @subpackage  Timber
 * @since   Timber 0.2
 */

$templates = array( 'archive-article.twig', 'index.twig' );

$context = Timber::context();

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

$context['title'] = 'Archive: Article';

$context['categories'] = $post->terms( array(
    'query' => [
        'taxonomy' => 'article_type',
    ],
) );

$context['article'] = new \Timber\PostQuery($args);

Timber::render( $templates, $context );
```

Any help from a second pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks yet by visiting Settings → Permalinks? Because if you register a new custom post type, the archive will only work as soon as you flush your permalinks.

Comment: Thanks, @Gchtr - yes, but always a good reminder.

Comment: Okay, next question: Did you put `register_post_type()` inside an `init` action, or do you call it directly in functions.php?

Comment: @Gchtr - also a good question and yes.

Comment: Okay, there could be many more reasons why this happens. From the code examples you provided, it’s hard to tell. Apparently, WordPress doesn’t reach archive-article.php at all. There could be a plugin that interferes with this, so disabling all plugins, flushing permalinks and checking whether that’s the reason would be my next check. And then I’d use [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) or `get_queried_object()` to check what happens on that archive page. If you find new information, it would be helpful to add it to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the archive slug to you custom post regisration, in addition to has_archive?

`"rewrite" => array("slug" => "articles"),`